# Bash Scripting- Grep/Awk output as input to another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, awk

I have a script that runs against a file and that takes arguments from a user and is sent through grep and awk to get the desired column. It will return multiple lines. What I want to do is read (or something of the like) through the output from grep|awk and run that through another script (./lookup). My question is how can I loop through each line and run what is on that line through my script inside the script. Hope this makes sense, I'm new to scripting and linux.

```
#!/bin/sh
x=$(grep "$*" "$c"|awk '{print $6}')
while read LINE   
do
./lookup $x
done
```

This seems to work but only for the first line of the output. It also requires me to hit enter to get the output from the ./lookup script. Any ideas or help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe the output of `grep` and `awk` to the loop:

```
grep "$*" "$c" | awk '{print $6}' | while read LINE
do
    ./lookup "$LINE"
done
```

BTW, it's not usually necessary to use both `grep` and `awk`, since `awk` can do regexp matching. So you can write:

```
awk -v re="$*" '$0 ~ re {print $6}' "$c" | while ...
```

The `-v` option sets an `awk` variable, and the `~` operator performs regular expression matching. `$0` refers to the whole input line.

Comment: I think `$*` here is referring to the list of arguments, which will be interpolated by the shell

Comment: I didn't realize that, thank you! My reasoning for the use of $* was in case more than one word was entered as an argument against the main script (./find Los Angeles). Is there an easier way to make sure the whole string is passed?

Comment: Usually users are expected to enclose the argument in quotes, e.g. `./find 'Los Angeles'`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use xargs instead of a loop

Also as barmar stated there is not need for grep.

```
awk -va="$*" '$0~a{print $6}' "$C" | xargs ./lookup
```